# Page Not Found error in ASP.NET MVC application on live server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I wrote a simple file upload application using ASP.NET MVC. I tested it successfully on my development machine, but when I attempt to use it on my live server any action I try results in a Page Not Found page.

With my hosting provider ([reliablesite.net](http://www.reliablesite.net/v3/index.asp)), I needed to specifically upload the `System.Web.Mvc` dll to my `bin` folder, so it is possible I am missing an assembly or something...but I should be getting a hard error like this one if that is the case:

[image]

[link to live site](http://anders-leet.com), try clicking the about or the upload etc to see what I am talking about.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the IIS setting "Check if file exists" for the web project.

What I had to do for one of my web projects was create a new extension for my web app.  So I go to INETMGR > WebApp > Properties > Directory Tab > Configuration Button > Mappings Tab > Add Button and set the Executable to aspnet_isapi.dll, set Extension to ".*" and un-check "Check that file exists".

Comment: I see. I imagine, then, that since I am on a shared server I cannot change this setting?

Comment: You probably can't do it yourself.  I called my hosting company and they did it for me while I was on the phone, it really shouldn't take too long.

Comment: This should be a per-application setting, not a site-wide setting.  You should be able to change this for your application.

Comment: @tvanfosson, depends on which version of IIS you're running.  Some versions don't have app pools.

Comment: Alright I have contacted my hosting service, hopefully they can assist me with this issue. Thank you for clarifying what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an IIS configuration issue.  Extensionless routing's possible, but it can be a bit of pain to get running.

[Phil Haack has an article on getting MVC apps running on IIS 6 here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) - I don't know how much access you'll have to the IIS console if it's a shared environment, so it may or may not be useful.